# I try to update a record of my bd with entity framework but it does not update it (It does not mark errors)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

What I want to do is a simple update of a record of my table and in this case I want to do it with linq but when I get to that piece of code does not mark me a mistake and executes all the lines but it does not update me registry:

Current Update Code:

```
Vehicle_Config vehiculo = (from conf in context.vehiculo_configuracion
                                       where conf.escuelaId.Equals(config.escuelaId)
                                       select new Vehicle_Config()
                                       {
                                           Id = conf.id,
                                       }).First();
           vehiculo.Idioma = config.Idioma;
            vehiculo.MensajeInicial = config.MensajeInicial;
            vehiculo.MensajeFinal = config.MensajeFinal;
            vehiculo.Repeticiones = config.Repeticiones;
            vehiculo.Timbre= config.Timbre;
           vehiculo.escuelaId = config.escuelaId;
            context.Entry(vehiculo).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
            return retorno;
```

I can already insert my registration but I want that when the school id does not become add but simply update the one that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

What version of the Entity Framework are you working on?

[Update Individual Records Using Entity Framework 6.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM4rO.png) 
[Update Multiple Records Using Entity Framework 6.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nag7C.png)